# saving base64 string as image in php using cordova

Tags: php, cordova, image-uploading

I am trying to save the captured image in my server as jpg/png,I decoded the string as base64 and uploaded it but when i open the image it says 'the file cant open'. I don't understand why this is happening or i just missed any code.

> > jquery

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
 var image = document.getElementById('dr_preview');
 image.src = imageURI;
 snapSrc = imageURI;
}
var img = document.getElementById('dr_preview');
var src = $('#dr_preview').attr('src');
console.log(src);
var dataparam = 'type=3&dr='+dr_value+'&image='+src;
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        url: 'http://localhost/v_2/dr-getDrDetails.php',
        data: dataparam,
        cache: true,
        success: function(data)
        {
        }
 });
```

> > php

```
$data = $_POST['image'];
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/v_2/scanedDR/'.$dr.'.PNG';
$file = fopen($filePath, 'w');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You just want image to save, as png and jpg, right

Comment: @Kumar yes dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, this function that convert base64 to image.

```
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
$ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb"); 

$data = explode(',', $base64_string);

fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1])); 
fclose($ifp); 

return $output_file; 
}
```

Comment: @veeran try to open your base64 encoded data in browser, if their is an error. Your jquery does not sending you correct data.

Comment: thanks dude i found the issue which is base64 string had spaces in it,i replaced the spaces with + and the issue resolved :).thanks for your support